# Mongo db crud operation

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I would like to perform CRUD operation on mongodb with parameters.

- Update the part of Json if possible.
- How can I map Json

Comment: What have you done already? please edit your post and put your code.

Answer (score 1):

To update a particular value only, uses `$set` update modifier.

Another way to update the value, is by calling the `collection.updatae()`, if you use this method then the document is replaced with another new document.

[collection.update() vs $set](http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/java-mongodb-update-document/)

For mapping here is the best example,

[MongoDb example](http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/java-mongodb-insert-a-document/)